# using count and joins across multiple tables

Tags: mysql

Example:
Table 1:

```
id   name

1    sim
2    sam
3    jas
```

Table 2

```
key   age
1     10
1     20
2     40
3     10
```

Table 3:

```
id    rating
2       7
2       6
3       8
3       7
1       9
```

Now, what I need is

number of rows that were grouped using group by in both the tables i.e table A and table B.

i.e

```
select t1.id, count(t2.key) as a, count(t3.id) as b
FROM 
table1 t1
LEFT JOIN 
table2 t2
ON 
t1.id = t2.key
LEFT JOIN 
table3 t3
ON 
t1.id = t3.id
GROUP BY t1.key, t2.id
```

Result I expect:

```
id   a  b
1    2  1
2    1  2
3    1  2
```

Comment: Is there an error when you run the query?  Why are you using left joints instead of inner joins?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql - Summing counts of multiple joined tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231409/mysql-summing-counts-of-multiple-joined-tables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting duplicates because you're creating a cross product between all 3 tables. Use `COUNT(DISTINCT)` to filter out the duplicates.

```
select t1.id, count(DISTINCT t2.age) as a, count(DISTINCT t3.rating) as b
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.key
LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.id = t3.id
GROUP BY t1.id
```

Comment: No, it does not give the expected results. It just gives 1 instead

Comment: Problem with my version of the query was that it returns exactly the same count for all the columns from all tables when I try to use count(columnname)

Comment: Stupid of me, of course there's just 1 distinct key/id, since they're the same as the ID you're joining on. Count the distinct values in the other column.

Comment: Could you please update your query ? I didn't quite get a hang of what you meant.